# Using variable as a label control name

Tags: vb6

In VB 6 How can I refer to control label using a variable instead  of a fixed name such as LUH01 (as below) which does not allow a Loop.

```
Frm_Dispo_Prof_Grille.LUH01.BackColor = &HFF00&
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to it via the [Controls Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445317%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

```
Frm_Dispo_Prof_Grille.Controls("LUH01").BackColor = &HFF00&
```

Be careful, however. If you need to refer to a property/method that is not one of the standard/built-in ones, you'll have to cast the control to a type:

```
Dim lbl as Label

Set lbl = Frm_Dispo_Prof_Grille.Controls("LUH01") 
lbl.BackColor = &HFF00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a control array

You can do that by creating 1 control, and set its Index property to 0 (instead of empty)

You can then Load new controls and use them all in a loop

For example to load some command buttons and position them in a loop:

```
'1 form with :
'  1 command button: name=Command1  index=0

'Number of command buttons to use in the loop
Private Const NRBUTTONS As Integer = 5

Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  'change the caption of the default button
  Command1(0).Caption = "Button 0"
  For intIndex = 1 To NRBUTTONS - 1
    'load an extra command button
    Load Command1(intIndex)
    'change the caption of the newly loaded button
    Command1(intIndex).Caption = "Button " & CStr(intIndex)
    'newly load command buttons are invisible by deafult
    'make the new command button visible
    Command1(intIndex).Visible = True
  Next intIndex
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  'arrange all loaded command buttons via a loop
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single
  Dim sngHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngHeight = ScaleHeight / NRBUTTONS
  For intIndex = 0 To NRBUTTONS - 1
    Command1(intIndex).Move 0, intIndex * sngHeight, sngWidth, sngHeight
  Next intIndex
End Sub
```